# How to remove single character before dash in the string?

Tags: php, regex

I have some string with this style:

```
$var = "a - it is a string";       // I want this output: 'it is a string'
$var = "m - it is second string";  // I want this output: 'it is second string'
```

So here is my pattern:

```
[single character in the first of string]<space>-<space>{anything} // I want just {anything}
```

How can I do that in PHP REGEX?

Here is my try *(altought does not work and I'm sure it is really far of what I want)*

```
preg_replace("/^\w\s+-\s+/","",$str);
```

---

Edit:

It should be noted that I use Persian characters in reality. Also here is a example:

```
$var = 'ی - این یک متن تست است';
```

Comment: There's an extraneous `/` forward slash, where it should be `\w` for the word char placeholder.

Comment: @mario I edited, tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$var = 'ی - این یک متن تست است';

echo preg_replace('/^\p{L}\h+-\h+/u', '', $var);
//=> این یک متن تست است
```

Regex used is:

```
^\p{L}  # match unicode letter at start
\h+     # match 1 or more horizontal space
-       # match 1 hyphen
\h+     # match 1 or more horizontal space
```

Important is use of `/u` modifier for unicode support in this regex.

Comment: A simple `.` will do the same as `\p{L}`, doesn't it ?

Comment: Yes but still `/u` is required and `.` can also match a whitespace not just any letter.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_replace('/^.\s-\s/', '', $var);
```

---

**Live PHP Demo**

http://ideone.com/fvIKBE

---

**Regex Explanation**

```
^.\s-\s

Assert position at the beginning of a line «^»
Match any single character that is NOT a line break character «.»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” «\s»
Match the character “-” literally «-»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” «\s»
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is mean of dot? `^.`? It means any single character?

Comment: Any single character that is NOT a line break character

Comment: You're very welcome @stack   :) If my answer helped you, please consider  accepting it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark ✔ in the middle of the vote arrows, tks !

Comment: your solution is fine, but honestly, I forgot to mention this point: My string is contained of Persian characters (not English). So your code is not useful for me, yes I know, it is my fault...

Comment: It works also with Persian characters, that's why using `[a-z]` wouldn't work  but `.` gets the job done.

Comment: No, I tested, it does not work. please check it for this: `ی - این یک متن تست است`

Comment: Look, really thanks for wiring your answer, and I gave you +1. Bur as you know your code is not for useful for me and it is because I did not mention the point (Persian characters) and it is really my fault. sorry

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to change the `/w` to `\w`.Secondly for matching a single character you can use a character class (if you just want to match alphabetical character) and for match the rest of string you can use modifier `.` followed by `*` :

```
preg_replace("/^[a-z]\s+-\s+.*/","",$str);
```

Also note that since you used the anchor `^` to specify the start of the string, if you are dealing with a multi line string you need to use flag `m` and `g` for match global.

```
preg_replace("/^[a-z]\s+-\s+.*/m","",$str);
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/gT9wB8/1

Reed more about regex https://www.regular-expressions.info

If you are dealing with unicode strings you can use flag `u` which makes your regex engine to match the unicode characters.

also note that you need to change range of your characters or use dot `.` which match just one character (but all the characters):

```
'/^.\s+-\s+.*/mu'
```

Or:

```
'/^[\u0622-\u06cc]\s+-\s+.*/mu'
```

Demo https://regex101.com/r/gT9wB8/2

Comment: @stack Check out the edit, and note that if you want to get the proper answer you better to provide a complete explain of your problem with adding a minimal example in your question.

Comment: `Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'g' in {address}`

Comment: @PedroLobito using unicode within regex can has a lot of scenarios, I meant that OP should add the real problem of dealing with unicode!

Comment: @stack the flag `g` is implicit with `preg_replace()`, you don't need to mention it. check the edit.

Comment: Look, really thanks for wiring your answer, and I gave you +1. Bur as you know your code is not for useful for me and it is because I did not mention the point (Persian characters) and it is really my fault. sorry